# Assigning new array from existing array php only shows last value of array

Tags: php, html, arrays, echo

I have a slight problem here. I have the following code that I create a search query, and im trying to take "$row" array and create a new array called "$item" so I can echo the values inside my div statement. This code works, and I do echo the $item array with the 'follower_username' values, however only the last value gets echoed out. I have values inside my database Nathan, Brett, Nathan2 and it only echoes Nathan2, or the last value of the array $item.

Here is my code:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM followers
WHERE username='$username'");
?>

<?php

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

  {
 $item = $row;

}


?>


<body>
<div id="contentwrap">
    <div rel="scrollcontent2">
       <?php echo $item['follower_username'];?> <img style="width: 50px; height: auto;"<?php echo '<img src="/user_photo/' . $item['follower_username'] . '.jpeg" />';?>
</div>
```

I hope I can get this resolved, it is bugging me! Thank you for any help!!

Comment: You need to put your echo item line inside the while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is reassigning the value of item to the current row each time.

$row will be an object of table row values from the resulting query so if you want all the rows in an $item variable that would need to be an array to store each result, instead of storing the current row in the same variable for each row.

You will then need to iterate that array to display each result.

```
$i = 0;
$item = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $item[$i] = $row;
  $i++;
}

<div>
  <?php 
    foreach ($item as $value)
    {
       echo $value['follower_username'];
    }
  ?>
</div>
```

Below is an example to show some shorthand versions of the same idea:
    $item = array();

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $item[] = $row;
}

<div>
  <ul>
  <?php foreach ($item as $value): ?>
    <li><?php echo $value['follower_username']; ?></li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you everyone! I finally got it with your code. But modified to my needs slightly. It works well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

What that does is grab the next row in the result set, and assign it to the variable `$row`. Each time the loop runs, it assigns the latest row to `$item`. So to store the whole result set, use

```
$item[] = $row.
```

I'm sure what you are trying to accomplish with our next line of code. To show all items you need something like

```
foreach($item as $singleItem)
{
echo $singleItem['follower_username']."<br>";
  }
```